# Principles and design patterns for the design of ontologies

Tags: ontology

I'm studying ontology in *Semantic Web* and I tried creating my own ontology by using *Protégé* after following [these steps](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk/protegeowltutorial/resources/ProtegeOWLTutorialP4_v1_3.pdf) to create the ontology of *Pizzas*.

I just had a feeling that it seems to be similar to [software design](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html) such as defining classes, relationships, ... A very basic question comes to my mind that: What are Ontology Design Principles?

Answer (score 4):

The [Ontology Design Patterns wiki](http://ontologydesignpatterns.org/) is an open repository of ontology engineering design patterns analogous to software engineering design patterns. There is an accompanying book, linked from the site.

There is an older site [here](http://odps.sourceforge.net/odp/html/index.html) that doesn't seem to be updated, but is still a valuable resource.

A more detailed answer may depend somewhat on the kind of ontology your building and what your use cases are. Ontology building encompasses everything from lightweight schema-type ontologies through to large biomedical ontologies. These may required different engineering approaches. The former may not require much more than RDFS. The latter typically uses more of the expressive power of OWL. The kinds of engineering approaches will vary.

If your use cases tend more towards the latter then a very good place to start would be some of the papers by Alan Rector (e.g. on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=qolPoFgAAAAJ)). In my opinion these give a very good engineering-oriented perspective, in particular for effective use of description logics. But there are other books that cover ontology building from other perspectives than engineering ones, e.g. [Building ontologies with BFO](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/building-ontologies-basic-formal-ontology).